# Criar Array Multidimencional Dinamicamente em PHP

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

Talvez essa pergunta já tenha sido feita mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse. Acredito que essa dúvida seja simples mas como não sou nenhum especialista em PHP, não consegui resolvê-la.

Seguinte:

Na empresa onde trabalho, temos um ERP onde são registrados os pedidos de venda da empresa. Por decisão da diretoria, vamos passar a utilizar um ERP online com foco para o Faturamento/Financeiro, mas preciso exportar (via API deles) os pedidos de venda gerados no nosso sistema.

O que não estou conseguindo é gerar um *array* multidimensional com as parcelas de cada pedido (tenho certeza que é um problema de construção mas ainda não resolvi).

A seguir, segue um exemplo de como seria a sintaxe caso fossem dados fixos:

```
$chave->lista_parcelas = array(
    "parcela" => array(
        array(
            "data_vencimento" => "30/11/2019",
            "numero_parcela" => "001",
            "valor" => 10.50
        ),
        array(
            "data_vencimento" => "05/12/2019",
            "numero_parcela" => "002",
            "valor" => 10.49
        ),
        array(
            "data_vencimento" => "10/12/2019",
            "numero_parcela" => "003",
            "valor" => 10.49
        )
    )
);
```

A seguir, a maneira como tentei montar isso (lembrando que as informações vem de um banco de dados):

```
$string_parc = "array('parcela' => array(";
$qt_parc = 0;
$string_PARC = "select * from VENPEDIDOSPAR ";
$string_PARC .= "where ";
$string_PARC .= "EMP_COD = ".$emp_cod." and ";
$string_PARC .= "PED_NUM = ".$ped_num;
$query_PARC = ibase_query($connection, $string_PARC);
while ($row_PARC = ibase_fetch_object($query_PARC)) {
    $qt_parc++;

    $vencto = new DateTime($row_PARC->VENCIMENTO);
    $vencto = date_format($vencto, "d/m/Y");

    $string_parc .= (($qt_parc == 1) ? "" : ",");
    $string_parc[] = "array('data_vencimento' => '$vencto',
                                'numero_parcela' => $qt_parc,
                                'valor' => $row_PARC->VALOR)";
}
$string_parc .= "))";

$chave->lista_parcelas = $string_parc;
```

Não dá erro mas as informações não são gravadas. O pessoal do suporte disse que o código está entrando como string na parte de parcelas (também acho), mas não consigo fazer da maneira correta.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Seria algo mais ou menos assim https://repl.it/repls/StaidRaggedSandbox

Comment: Marcos, fiz algumas alterações para ler da tabela e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado. Ajudou muito.